# I'm trying to import CSV file using pandas, But I'm getting Error. (look at pic)

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataset, jupyter

[What am I doing wrong?? I'm trying to import a csv file using pandas, i either get an error stating file can't be found or a unicodeerror message?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mEHoE.jpg)

Comment: could be an error inside the .csv file

Comment: Don't post a picture. Copy and paste the error here, along with an example row of your csv file.

Comment: just a thought tho, you don't need to put : `import pandas` and then `import pandas as pd`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should escape your backslashes on Windows - \U is interpreted as a unicode character directive in the string.

Try:

```
C:\\Users\\... etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
import pandas as pd
import string
import io
uploaded = files.upload()
df = pd.read_csv(io.BytesIO(uploaded['pokemon.csv']))
df
```

don't mind the csv file name
just put the file instead of 'pokemon.csv'